# How to load content (stream or byte[]) of xamarin shared images on pcl?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a xamarin forms solution with with projects PCL, Android and iOS. I have several images in the PCL project that I make a link into projects Android and iOS (drawable/resources folder). Therefore, if I want display this images in a Image control in pcl project I can just use  and works fine.

But, I need load the content of this images into a Stream or byte[] (of course, is trivial convert from/to ) to invoke a service ahead.

How I can accomplish this task? If there is a way in pcl project is better, but if will need code in specifics platforms, no problem.

Note: This task would easy if we embedded the images as resources in the pcl project, but I don't want this, I don't want increase app size embedding duplicated images.

Note: There are other "similar" questions, but loading content from embedded resources, please, this is not the case here.

Comment: You can use DependencyService in your platform project and convert the image into byte[] and return it to your pcl. If i understand the question correctly that's what you need.

Comment: Thanks @Dilmah, but where I find the images? What is the standard folder of the images on drawable (android) and resources (ios) platforms?

Comment: Hi Diego, this is not a duplicated question. The cited question is about embedded resource images, this is not the case here. See my note in the question. Thanks!

Comment: Hi! What is the build action of the images in your PCL project? The images in your platform code is added as a link to the PCL file?

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza, the build action of the images in my PCL project is "Content", I don't want embedded it. Yesss, the images in my platform code is added as a link to the PCL files, with the appropriate build action, e.g., AndroidResource.

Comment: Flag retracted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use dependancy and need code in specifics platforms to get base64 string from image and it take path automatically in local

In Pcl Project

```
public interface IGetBase64
    {
        string GenerateBase64(string FileName);
    }
```

In Ios Render

```
public string GenerateBase64(string FileName)
    {
        byte[] b = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FileName);
        string s = Convert.ToBase64String(b);
        return s;
    }
```

In Android

```
public string GenerateBase64(string FileName)
    {
        byte[] b = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FileName);
        string s = Convert.ToBase64String(b);
        return s;
    }
```

Comment: What is the standard folder of the images on drawable (android) and resources (ios) platforms?

Comment: in android Resources/drawable and in iOS Resources folder

Comment: My question is about app runtime, if I put the file "image.png" in the Resources/Drawable folder of android project, how can I access it at runtime? What is the absolute/relative path to this image?

Comment: what you want Path or content ? please be clarify with your question

Comment: using this answer you get image content and you can invoke a service ahead

Comment: Are you saying that System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("image.png") work?

Comment: No Ziyad, this not work, we need know the full path of file, if I try just System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("image.png") it will find "/image.png" and, of course, my file not exists in the root of SO.

Comment: Are you want access resource file and send it content via service?

Comment: Yes, this is my question! :))

Answer (score 0):

You can add the images in the `Asset` folder in Android platform and in `Resources` folder in iOS platform.

Then get the path of the image in platforms:

In Android, just add the prefix `file:///android_asset/` to the image name.

In iOS, use the code to get the path:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"IMAGE_FILE_NAME" ofType:@"IMAGE_TYPE"];
```

Then return the path value to PCL via dependency service.